# Acceptance ratio as metric score

Tags: python

I built a binary classification model (1 = reject, 0 = accept) in which we try to optimize the acceptance and sensitivity. We want to accept as many observations possible for which the sensitivity is at least 98%.

To create the acceptance score, we made this code:

```
    tn, fn, fp, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    return (tn + fn) / (tn + fn + fp + tp)
```

However, this code returns the same results for every threshold. We expected that acceptance score would increase when the sensitivity decreased. And thus, would be lower at a higher threshold. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using your own `confusion_matrix` function or `scikit-learn's`?

Comment: Sci-kit learn's

Comment: The syntax for scikit-learn's is `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(...).ravel()`